# What are the meanings of the field 'on_cpu' in struct task_struct and the field 'cpu' in struct thread_info?

Tags: linux, kernel

I want to know which cpu the current process is running on in Linux system, 
and I have two choices —

1. get the field `on_cpu` in struct `task_struct` or
2. get the field `cpu` in struct `thread_info`.

I write a kernel module programming to probe the two fields, and get the 
result below:

```
[ 3991.419185] the field 'on_cpu' in task_struct is :1
[ 3991.419187] the field 'cpu' in thread_info is :0
[ 3991.419199] the field 'on_cpu' in task_struct is :1
[ 3991.419200] the field 'cpu' in thread_info is :0
[ 3991.419264] the field 'on_cpu' in task_struct is :1
[ 3991.419266] the field 'cpu' in thread_info is :1
[ 3991.419293] the field 'on_cpu' in task_struct is :1
[ 3991.419294] the field 'cpu' in thread_info is :1
[ 3991.419314] the field 'on_cpu' in task_struct is :1
[ 3991.419315] the field 'cpu' in thread_info is :1
[ 3991.419494] the field 'on_cpu' in task_struct is :1
[ 3991.419495] the field 'cpu' in thread_info is :0
[ 3991.419506] the field 'on_cpu' in task_struct is :1
[ 3991.419507] the field 'cpu' in thread_info is :1
```

and I don't know the correctly meaning of the two fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `cpu` field in `thread_info` specifies the number of the CPU where the process is executing on. This is what you are searching for.

The `on_cpu` flag in `task_struct` is actually a lock when context switching and wanting to have interrupts enabled during a context switch in order to avoid high latency by having an unlocked runqueue. Basically when it's 0 then the task can be moved to a different cpu.